# LocationServices.FusedLocationApi .getLastLocation returns null on Android Kitkat

Tags: android, location

Am building an Android app that needs to get the user's current location.

However, am using Google Play Services to get that and am following this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2015/02/android-location-api-using-google-play-services/.

I have two real android devices : one with Jelly bean; and the other with Kitkat. When i run it on Jelly bean, it works fine even with Wifi and GPS turned off both but, when i run it on Kitkat it always returns null for the Location untill i turn GPS on.
So i want it to work on all devices without having to turn GPS or Wifi on.

Have you any idea ?

am using the same code as in the tutorial.

Thanks